# @JoinColumn uses different column name

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, orm

I am using `@JoinColumn` annotation for one-to-many mapping as:

`@JoinColumn(name="domainId",referencedColumnName="domainId")`.

But, in the foreign key column name in the table shows as `domain_id`. So could anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: WHAT created the table? you ? or your JPA provider?

Answer (score 2):

The attributes in @JoinColumn are the names of the database table column.

So this must be domain_id

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using one of the `org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy` implementations that replaces the camelcase with underscores. Like the `org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy` column parsing method:

```
/**
 * Convert mixed case to underscores
 */
public String columnName(String columnName) {
    return addUnderscores(columnName);
}
```

I would suggest using the `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` as it should parse the column name **as it is**:

```
@Override
public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
    return name;
}
```

In order to change that set it in your sessionFactory config:

```
hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=
    org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

If you still have problems you may need to write you own NamingStrategy:

```
public class CustomNamingStrategy extends SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy{

    ...

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name
                , JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return getIdentifier(name.toString(), name.isQuoted(), jdbcEnvironment);
    }

}
```

Comment: Solved my problem by using PhysicalNamingStratergyStandardImpl.Thanks a lot